# CSS not linked correctly after moving file

Tags: html, css

to submit an assignment, I must put my css and html file in a separate folder "assignment", when I did that the CSS and bootstrap is not showing up in my webpage. I know i need to update the css link, so that's what I did below, but it didn't work so how do I correctly do that? [directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jz8KP.png)

from:

```
<link href="styles.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">

<link href="bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
```

to:

```
<link href="assignment/styles.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">

<link href="bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: Can you update your code? Nothing is showing up right now as it seems. Edit: Oh, you added. Can you tell me your project directory style?

Comment: If you moved both files *together*, you do not need to change the file path (IE if you moved the HTML and CSS files into the assignment directory, but they are still in the same directory as each other).

Comment: Do you have your HTML file and CSS file both in the Assignment directory? if Yes, no need to change the path

Comment: Remember that the locations above are relative to the HTML file. For example, if the HTML file is in a folder called sparky and the CSS files are in sparky/assignment, your link would point to "assignment/whatever.css". In your example above, both the HTML and CSS must reside in the same folder. You may need to provide more info about your file structure to intelligently answer this question.

Comment: Yes, both css and html files are in the same folder

Answer (score 0):

If your `index.html` (which you want to put the codes) is out of the `assignment` folder and the css files are in the assignment, use

```
<link href="./assignment/styles.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">

<link href="./assignment/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
```

or if all of them are in the same assignment folder, you don't need to change the path.

Comment: I moved both to the same assignment folder but it's still not working ( css and bootstrap not showing)

Comment: Never mind, turns out I forgot to move the second css file, thank you though! Although, I have run into another problem, it seems some of my images that aren't linked to the web but to a directory aren't loading, i have the local images in an "img" folder in the same bigger folder with the "assignment" folder.

here's the code I originally had:

<img src="img/arts-build-close-up-273230.png" class="home-image" alt="User Experience Workflow">

how do i fix it?

Comment: ./assignment/img/arts-build-close-up-273230.png would fix it

Comment: the image is not located in the assignment folder though, and i can't move it there because my instructor only wants the html and css files in the assignment folder

Comment: I need a screenshot of your folder directory. Nevertheless, if img folder is in the same folder as index and assignment folder, you can just use the normal "./img/arts-build-close-up-273230.png". If it is one level higher, "../img/arts-build-close-up-273230.png"

Comment: I added a link to a screenshot of my directory

Comment: If you got the css files working with "assignment/", then "img/" should be fine though. This is getting weird

Comment: actually the css files worked without changing anything so with href= "styles.css"..

Comment: So the index is IN the assignment folder, I get it now. That was way too confusing. "../img/arts-build-close-up-273230.png" would solve this. ".." will leave the directory by one level which will go up to the screenshot and start from there.

Comment: what you're saying makes complete sense, yet it still didn't work :/ Thank you for the help though! here's what I put:  <img src="../img/arts-build-close-up-273230.png" class="home-image" alt="User Experience Workflow">

Comment: Clear the caches. Ctrl + F5 or Command + Shift + R in Mac. Caches are one heck of a problem sometimes.

Comment: so, i tried even putting a random picture from google and it's still not showing up so I think it's another problem ugh

Comment: I finally figured it out! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

If your index.html , style.css  and  bootstrap.min.css File in assignment folder and for both css haven't separate folder, then bellow code apply

```
<link href="styles.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
```

If your index.html , style.css  and  bootstrap.min.css File in assignment folder and for both css have separate folder which name is css, then bellow code apply

```
<link href="css/styles.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
```